# Try import CSV to MongoDB with PHP shell_exec() but seems not work

Tags: php, mongodb, csv

I am trying to import a CSV to server's mongoDB by php. I already done the update file part and now I can get the CSV file that client update to the server. so now I am trying to import CSV file to mongoDB by using shell_exec() , here is my PHP code.

`$importCommand = 'mongoimport -d test -c test --type csv --file  yourfile.csv --headerline';
$output = shell_exec($importCommand.' 2>&1');
echo $output;`

when I run this part of code in terminal by php -f it works(I know my CSV is not there so no import has been made),

`$ mongoimport -d test -c test --type csv --file  yourfile.csv --headerline
2017-03-22T13:46:22.668+0800    Failed: open yourfile.csv: no such file or directory
2017-03-22T13:46:22.668+0800    imported 0 documents"`

as can be seen this works perfectly fine. The 'mongoimport' can be found and work fine.
However when I add this to my php that use to update the file the output become

sh: mongoimport: command not found

Any idea how to solve this problem? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know, its due to my webserver process won't necessarily be set up with the same configuration as your own account.

MongoDB's bin is for me,
but apache user is '_www'.

so I need to fix this privilege to get my PHP run mongoimport via safari.
or input /usr/local/mongodb/bin/mongoimport to get it done

Thanks StackOF I can answer myself by just posting here